# Can I get a PTypeInfo from a string?

Tags: delphi, rtti

This is probably going to be a "no", but is there any way I can use Delphi's RTTI, either old-school or the 2010 extended RTTI, to pass in a string containing the name of a type, specifically the name of an enumerated type, and have it give me the PTypeInfo for that type?  I've looked through RTTI.pas and TypInfo.pas and I don't see any function that would do that, but I might have missed something.

What I'm looking for:

```
var
  info: PTypeInfo;
begin
  info := GetTypeInfoFromName('TComponentStyle');
end;
```

Or something like that.  Thing is, the name of the enumerated type would be passed in; it wouldn't be known at compile time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following should work with the qualified name.

Qualified Name is: `UnitName.TypeName`

```
type
 ETypeNotFound = class(Exception);

function GetTypeInfoFromName(aTypeName : String) : pTypeInfo;
var
 C : TRttiContext;
 T : TRttiType;
begin
 T := C.FindType(aTypeName);
 if Not Assigned(T) then
    raise ETypeNotFound.CreateFmt('Type %s is not found',[aTypeName]);

 result := T.Handle;
end;
```

Comment: It should work for enum type name.   Which is different than enumeration element names.